# Наследование потомков класса

Tags: наследование, delphi, классы

Описание класса:

unit unit2;

```
interface
Type

TCircle = class
private
  ciArea:real;
protected
  ciradius:integer;
  procedure setciArea;
public
  property cirradius: integer read ciradius;
  property cirarea  : real read ciArea;
  constructor create(radius:integer);
end;

TCylinder = class(TCircle)
private
  cyArea:real;
protected
  cyradius,cyheight:integer;
  procedure setcyArea;
public
  property cylradius: integer read cyradius;
  property cylheight: integer read cyheight;
  property cylarea  : real read cyArea;
  constructor create(radius, height:integer);
end;

implementation

constructor Tcircle.Create(radius:integer);
begin
  ciradius:= radius;
  setciArea;
end;

constructor TCylinder.create(radius,height:integer);
begin
   cyradius:= radius;
   cyheight:= height;
   setcyArea;
end;

procedure TCircle.setciArea;
begin
  ciArea:=cirradius*cirradius*3.14;
end;

 procedure TCylinder.setcyArea;
begin
  cyArea:=2*3.14*cylradius*(cylradius+cylheight);
end;

end.
```

Программный модуль:

```
procedure TCircles.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
a,b:integer;
begin
   if RadioGroup1.ItemIndex=-1 then
      begin
         ShowMessage('Выберите фигуру');
         end;
                  if (Shape is TCircle) then
         begin
         a:=strtoint(edit1.Text);
         shape:=Tcircle.create(a);
         label3.Caption:='Площадь окружности = ' + floattostr(shape.cirarea);
         end;
                  if (Shape is TCylinder) then
         begin
                  a:=strtoint(edit1.Text);
                  b:=strtoint(edit2.Text);
         shape:=Tcylinder.create(a,b);
 //label3.Caption:='Площадь цилиндра = ' + floattostr(shape.cylarea); 
         end;
      end;
```

Проблема возникает на "закомментированной" строке:

> [DCC Error] Unit1.pas(60): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'cylarea'

Ошибка возникает из-за того, что мы работает с базовым классом и с его потомком, поэтому при вызове класса-потомка у нас возникает ошибка, или с чем-то другим это связано? И как эту ошибку избежать, если мне надо, чтобы иерархия классов сохранилась для данной программы, без абстрактных классов?

Comment: WTF? Почему **цилиндр** наследует от **круга**?

Comment: @tkoff, сделайте лучше реализацию конкретных фигур через один базовый - TShape.

Comment: karmadro4, таково задание к сожалению.
Asen, в том то и дело что нужно сделать наследование "цилиндра" от круга, без базовых классов..

Comment: Уместнее была бы композиция.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну раз такое задание....

То, что написано `TCylinder = class(TCircle)` - это еще не наследование. Свойства и методы родителя и наследника у вас никак не пересекаются. Радиус должен быть один. площадь (area) должна быть одна...

Псевдокод:

```
TCircle.area:=PI*TCircle.radius*TCircle.radius;
TCylinder.area:=2*(inherited area)+2*PI*(inherited radius)*TCylinder.height;
```

Answer (score 2):

Я как понимаю Shape у вас обявлен как TCircle

поменяйте

```
floattostr(shape.cylarea);
```

на

```
floattostr(TCylinder(shape).cylarea);
```

или

```
floattostr((shape as TCylinder).cylarea);
```

Хотя можно cyradius вообше убрать из класса TCylinder и использовать радиус предка (ciradius),будет хотябы смысл в наследовании.

Comment: спасибо, это помогло, ошибки нет, но теперь при выборе класса "цилиндр" выполняется процедура для "окружности". Так происходит, потому что у нас базовый класс - "окружность" и при работе с "цилиндрами" наша программа все равно обращается к "окружности"?

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте виртуальную ф-цию площадь, которая у круга будет честно возвращать площадь круга, а у цилиндра - цилиндра. Тогда всё встанет на свои места.